# How can I add an image to a table in Perl?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have developed a database using Perl DBI and display using Perl CGI. Can you please suggest syntax for adding an image to the table and its background in the database.

Comment: Are you trying to put this image in the database, or display this image in the web page?

Answer (score 3):

I would just insert a text field containing the address/name of the image, place the images in a directory and load them at runtime.

Comment: +1 - This is the best way, since it will allow the browser to cache the images if it can.

Answer (score 2):

Insert the binary data into a field defined to hold [blobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object). Just be certain that only binary data gets inserted. Insertion can be done the same way you insert text into a text field.

You can also store the path to the image in a text field and later retrieve the image via that path.